# Issue converting scala case class to spark dataset with embedded options that wrap monads

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset

I ran into a problem when trying to convert a Seq of case classes into a Spark Dataset today. I thought I'd share the solution here as it was tough to pin down.

I have a case class I am trying to convert to a Dataset

```
case class Foo(name: String, names: Option[List[String]])
val myData: Seq[Foo] = Seq(Foo("A", Some(List("T","U"))),
                           Foo("B", Some(List("V","W"))))

val myFooDataset = sparkSession.createDataset(myData)
```

This errors out and complains that there is no encoder.  How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

The answer in this case is to convert your embedded Lists to Seq. In fact, Just having a column that is a List (without being wrapped in an Option) will work but as soon as you wrap it in an Option it needs to be a Seq instead.

```
case class Foo(name: String, names: Option[Seq[String]])
val myData: Seq[Foo] = Seq(Foo("A", Some(Seq("T","U"))),
                           Foo("B", Some(Seq("V","W"))))

val myFooDataset = sparkSession.createDataset(myData)
```